# Developing a Tower Defense game - Help on targeting one single object at a time

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, canvas, this

Hello fellow Stack Overflow programmers,

If you've ever played a tower defense game, here's where you should land. I've been trying to develop this tower defense game for a pretty long time, and I got stuck on the question of targeting one single object at a time within a range of the defense. I've got an idea of what I should do, but does not work completely.

```
this.defensesInRangeArcher = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < buildArcherX.length; i++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < buildArcherY.length; i++) {
        if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(buildArcherX[i] - this.x, 2) + Math.pow(buildArcherY[i] - this.y, 2)) <= arch.radius + 7) {
            this.defensesInRangeArcher += 1;
            if (!v.singleAimArcher) {
                this.attackByArcher = true;
                v.singleAimArcher = true;
            }
        } else {
            this.attackByArcher = false;
            v.singleAimArcher = false;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the above code, that is the targeting part of the game. One of the buildings I'm developing is the single-shot archer tower. The for statements are used to access all the archer tower coordinates and the if statement asks if "this" (or you could say, enemy) is within the range of any of the archer towers. `this.defensesInRangeArcher` just tells how many archer towers are in range.

I will repeat again, the problem I ran into was that without the `v.singleAimArcher` variable, the archer tower(s) will affect all in range. I tried to fix this problem by adding the `v.singleAimArcher` variable so only one will be affected. This worked great if there was only one archer tower in place but when multiple were placed down, it didn't work out great.

Does anyone have an alternate solution for this?

Comment: You're going to run into geometric trouble if you're not careful. Testing all towers vs. all potential targets is an N x M type of thing which can be a huge drag on performance. Optimizing this involves putting all the targets into a grid and each tower tests only against elements inside the grid squares within range. This cuts the number of tests required dramatically, but you'll have to reassign each target to the grid before each test.

Comment: Also don't forget towers tend to target the same thing until it's out of range or destroyed and only re-target when they have no target set. This also helps with performance.

Comment: @tadman Do you have a solution?

Comment: Honestly, none of that code makes any sense, I'm just kicking out ideas here. For one, whatever `v` is hasn't been made clear.

Comment: @tadman the v is a global variable

Comment: Well *that* explains everything.

Comment: @tadman I did to my best ability to explain what is going on in the piece of code, if you need anymore information, I'll be happy to give you it. And _that_ means what?

Comment: You've given too much, and not enough at the same time. You've got a lot of work to do here before you're ready to ask a question. This needs to be boiled down into something more digestible, something you can more easily explain to people. I can't test the code here, it's incomplete, and I'm not even sure what you want it to do.

Comment: @tadman Do you want my entire code I've written so far? And hopefully read it and break down the solution?

Comment: Nobody wants all the code you've written. This is Stack Overflow. If you can't produce a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then it's very hard for people to help you. If you're really in a jam you can try forums or a [mentoring service](http://codementor.io).

Comment: @tadman Ok, I'll try my best to give you code that explains what is going on.

Comment: Key here is something short, self-contained, and easily explained. I know that's not always easy, but it's essential.

Comment: @tadman And just a little question, are you a mentor yourself?

Comment: It's something I've done, yes.

Comment: @tadman You might know what I'm going to ask you, so, are you willing to?

Comment: @tadman Here's the js file I contained the code in, have a look at it. https://jsfiddle.net/qc4md83t/

Comment: @tadman You going to answer me?